# materialize css select box issues in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

materializecss select box in Internet explorer 9 or more it can't be able to scroll using mouse button,click on the scroll bar inside the select box it diapers. But all other remaining browsers working properly.
i have also attached the sample screen shot,kindly help to solve this issue..

[image]

Comment: Materialize css browser support: Chrome 35+, Firefox 31+, Safari 7+, IE 10+. A thread on IE9 support for it: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1230

Comment: Could you copy paste your code?

Comment: This link will help to slove: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/901

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a behavior for mouse down events in addition to triggering a close. Check out issue #901 at https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/901